# If loops on Excel for multiple options

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code set up to draft an email based on the value in column B which works fine. (If there is any text in column A it will run this)

Column B could have any of 25 options which are on the `Statuses` worksheet also, alongside the relevant email address relating to each option which is then entered  in the `.To` field. I'm wondering if there's any way that I can run the if loop without having to write each section out and amend 25 times (the below code shows two of the 25)

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text 'ignore case sensitivity when comparing strings

Sub SendDraft()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim OL As Outlook.Application, ES As Worksheet, r As Long, i As Long
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
Dim path As String
Dim body As String
Dim body2 As String
Dim body3 As String
Dim body4 As String


body = ",<br><br>Please find attached a draft invoice for "
body2 = "<br><br>Please respond with any agreement or dispute no later than 4:30pm on <b>"
body3 = "</b>, otherwise a full invoice will be raised to the value of the attached draft.<br><br>Many thanks,"


    r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To r
    With Cells(i, 1)

            If .Value <> "" And Cells(i, 2) = Sheets("Statuses").Range("G6").Value Then
                    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
                    With objMail
                    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "xxx@xxx.com"
                    .To = Sheets("Statuses").Range("H6").Value & ";" & Sheets("Statuses").Range("I6").Value
                    .CC = "xxx@xxx.com"
                    .Subject = "Your " & Cells(i, 5).Value & " licence - " & Cells(i, 4).Value
                    .HTMLBody = "Dear " & Cells(i, 2) & body & Cells(i, 26).Text & " defect charges." & body2 & Cells(i, 27).Text & body3
                    .Display

End With
End If

If .Value <> "" And Cells(i, 2) = Sheets("Statuses").Range("G7").Value Then
                    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
                    With objMail
                    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "xxx@xxx.com"
                    .To = Sheets("Statuses").Range("H7").Value & ";" & Sheets("Statuses").Range("I7").Value
                    .CC = "xxx@xxx.com"
                    .Subject = "Your " & Cells(i, 5).Value & " licence - " & Cells(i, 4).Value
                    .HTMLBody = "Dear " & Cells(i, 2) & body & Cells(i, 26).Text & " defect charges." & body2 & Cells(i, 27).Text & body3
                    .Display

End With
End If
End With

Next i

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("a3:a1000")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No draft charge(s) to send - please enter text in column A for the appropriate draft charge(s) you wish to send."
End If

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: I guess the only part that changes depending on the value of column G is line `.To = Sheets("Statuses").Range("H6").Value & ";" & Sheets("Statuses").Range("I6").Value`? In that case, make a secondary sub with a parameter related to this value, and call it from main Sub

Answer (score 0):

For demonstration purposes I will only show you how to create the `.To` field , without using all those `if-statements`. You can then build this logic into your existing code. For the sake of simplicity, I will assume that your set up in the first worksheet looks like this:

[image]

and on the `Statuses` worksheet, the setup looks like this:

[image]

In this case you can just use a lookup function like so:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim sendTo As String
Dim lookUpRng As Range
Dim emailsRng1 As Range
Dim emailsRng2 As Range
Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your worksheet")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Statuses")
Set lookUpRng = sht2.Range("G3:G27")
Set emailsRng1 = sht2.Range("H3:H27")
Set emailsRng2 = sht2.Range("I3:I27")

With sht1
    Set rng = Range(.Range("B3"), .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cell In rng
    sendTo = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(cell.Value, lookUpRng, emailsRng1) & "; " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(cell.Value, lookUpRng, emailsRng2)
    Debug.Print sendTo
Next cell

End Sub
```

The result would look like that:

```
email1.14; email2.14
email1.15; email2.15
email1.16; email2.16
email1.21; email2.21
email1.22; email2.22
email1.19; email2.19
email1.25; email2.25
email1.25; email2.25
email1.19; email2.19
email1.25; email2.25
email1.25; email2.25
email1.25; email2.25
email1.1; email2.1
email1.1; email2.1
email1.13; email2.13
email1.22; email2.22
email1.23; email2.23
email1.24; email2.24
email1.25; email2.25
email1.1; email2.1
email1.19; email2.19
email1.25; email2.25
email1.25; email2.25
email1.25; email2.25
email1.25; email2.25
email1.17; email2.17
email1.18; email2.18
email1.19; email2.19
email1.20; email2.20
email1.1; email2.1
email1.1; email2.1
email1.22; email2.22
email1.23; email2.23
email1.25; email2.25
email1.1; email2.1
email1.25; email2.25
email1.25; email2.25
email1.25; email2.25
```

Another approach would be to define a `dictionary` and set up its `keys` to be the 25 options and the strings composed of the corresponding email addresses to be the `values`:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary

For Each cell In lookUpRng
    dict.Add cell.Value, cell.Offset(0, 1).Value & "; " & cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
Next cell
For Each cell In rng
    Debug.Print dict(cell.Value)
Next cell
```

For that you would need a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (VB editor>tools>references).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the only thing changing here is G6, H&, I6 to G7, H7, I7 and so on for the next 25 options, can you then do a for loop within the for loop:

```
For i = 3 To r
    With Cells(i, 1)

        For x = 6 To 31

            If .Value <> "" And Cells(i, 2) = Sheets("Statuses").Range("G" & x).Value Then
                Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

                With objMail
                    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "xxx@xxx.com"
                    .To = Sheets("Statuses").Range("H" & x).Value & ";" & Sheets("Statuses").Range("I" & x).Value
                    .CC = "xxx@xxx.com"
                    .Subject = "Your " & Cells(i, 5).Value & " licence - " & Cells(i, 4).Value
                    .HTMLBody = "Dear " & Cells(i, 2) & body & Cells(i, 26).Text & " defect charges." & body2 & Cells(i, 27).Text & body3
                    .Display

                End With
            End If

        Next x        

    End With
Next i
```

Good luck
BR
Fnk